# Hyperlink in datagrid

Tags: c#

I am inserting record in `datagrid` by binding it with data table and I had set autogenerate field ON for `datagrid`. Now all I want is first column which will comes in datagrid should be `hyperlink` field and when I will click on link it should redirect to another page. Please help

Comment: what your usng with C# ??

Comment: @DeshDeepSingh if he wants a redirect, most likely its asp.net

Comment: yeah but he should specify in tags I believe, even though we could figure it out.

Comment: @DeshDeepSingh hence the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like :

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:HyperLink ID="Edit" runat="server" Text="Edit" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("DataKeyName", "~/View.aspx?Id={0}") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

**Edit:**

You need to change the column type to a Hyperlink column.
and where to set is your job Sandesh

```
<Columns>
    <asp:hyperlinkfield headertext="NewsHeadline"
          datatextfield="NewsHeadline"
          datanavigateurlfield="NewsURL" 
          datanavigateurlformatstring="http://{0}" />
</Columns>
```

Comment: Desh deep I want values comes in first column will be hyperlink field

Comment: cool, if it is helpful mark it as answer and upvote it please.

Comment: Deshdeep is it possible to pass value text of hyperlink into session when I click on it

Comment: yes, for that there are lot of related articles please go through them.